# CASE expression in a correlated sub query

Tags: sql-server, subquery, case, business-objects

The following code is a simplified and anonymised section of a query I have written. The purpose is to find a record in tblB using a correlated sub query, linked using tblA.ID and tblB.ID, and where there is a match, simply display 'Yes' for [Entry], otherwise display 'No ID Recorded'. Using a CASE expression, I am trying to achieve an outcome which translates to;

> WHEN there is a record matching THEN 'Yes'
>
> WHEN there is no record matching (i.e For tblA.ID, there is no
>   tblB.ID) THEN 'No ID Recorded'

I have used the set function ROW_NUMBER() to account for the fact that there may be more than one matching record in the sub query, in which case the >1 value being returned error will occur.

The code:

```
SELECT
    tblA.ID,
    tblA.StartDate,
    tblA.EndDate,
    --
    --Correlated sub query
    --
    (
      SELECT
        [Entry]
      FROM
        (
          SELECT
            CASE
              WHEN tblB.ID IS NULL THEN 'No ID Recorded'
              ELSE 'Yes'
            END [Entry],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tblB.StartDate DESC, tblB.ID DESC) [RowNo]
          FROM
            tblB
          WHERE
            tblA.ID = tblB.ID
            AND
            tblB.EndDate IS NULL
        ) sub
      WHERE
        [RowNo] = 1
    ) [Entry]
FROM
    tblA
WHERE
    /* Additional criteria */
```

When I run this however, the column displays NULL and not the string 'No ID Recorded' which I had hoped for. It does however correctly display 'Yes' where there is a match. I have tried applying the CASE expression to parent sub query, i.e:

```
(
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN [Entry] IS NULL THEN 'No ID Recorded'
      ELSE 'Yes'
    END [Entry]
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        tblB.ID [Entry],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tblB.StartDate DESC, tblB.ID DESC) [RowNo]
      FROM
        tblB
      WHERE
        tblA.ID = tblB.ID
        AND
        tblB.EndDate IS NULL
    ) sub
  WHERE
    [RowNo] = 1
) [Entry]
```

Still, NULLs are returned. When I execute the sub query as a query on its own, i.e:

```
SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN tblB.ID IS NULL THEN 'No ID Recorded'
      ELSE 'Yes'
    END [Entry]
FROM
        tblA
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblB    -- Left join to test the CASE expression
        ON tblA.ID = tblB.ID
```

Then it operates fine. This obviously doesn't have the ROW_NUMBER() function but it isn't required for this test.

I have included the business-objects tag as I am executing the query in Web Intelligence, which rules out the use of CTEs amongst other things.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose by using a completely different approach this might be achieved using:

```
SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN tblA.ID IN
        (
          SELECT
            tblB.ID
          FROM
            tblB
          WHERE 
            tblB.EndDate IS NULL
        )
        THEN 'Yes'
      ELSE 'No ID Recorded'
    END [Entry]
```

Seems to work, although why the original approach and CASE expression wasn't correct remains unsolved.